# How to create FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW in a schema, have to retrieve Data over db_link in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

How to create `FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW` in a schema? Have to retrieve Data over db_link in Oracle.

it doesn't allow me to create `FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW`, so I just created a normal view as:

```
(CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "schema"."view_name)
```

but it retrieves only few records.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504) says that `EDITIONABLE` is default.

Editions provide isolation mechanism which allows the same object to have several "instances" in the same database, but each of them being its own "version" (i.e. *edition*) which is different form its other editions.

(I imagine it something like *versioning*, or Smallworld GIS database's *alternative*, if you're familiar with it).

In order to use editioning, you have to enable editions for the user (using the ALTER USER command); did you do that? Note that it isn't reversible.

Also, could it be that view's (or your SELECT statement's) `WHERE` clause restrict number of rows, and not the `EDITIONABLE` parameter?

**[EDIT]**

If I understood you correctly, this is what is going on:

Database link points to user in another database (otherwise, you wouldn't use a DB link, right?). Let's call it LINK_USER. When connected as LINK_USER on that remote database, you run

```
select * from some_table where x = y
```

and get 100 rows.

Then, connected as LOCAL_USER, you created a DB link and a view which looks exactly like the previous SELECT:

```
create database link link_db connect to link_user ...

create or replace view v_some_table as
  select * from some_table@link_db where x = y
```

Finally, when you run (connected as LOCAL_USER)

```
select * from v_some_table
```

you don't get 100 rows but only 28 rows? Is that correct? If not, please, explain exactly what you did and how. Copy/paste of your SQL*Plus session would be nice.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
22992. 00000 -  "cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables"
*Cause:    A remote LOB column cannot be referenced.
*Action:   Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.

Comment: You can't select LOB columns via database link. Check which column(s) are BLOB or CLOB and remove them from SELECT statement. **OR**, wrap it into a subquery (so that you don't select it directly). Have a look here: https://technology.amis.nl/2012/07/02/select-a-blob-across-a-database-link-without-getting-ora-22992/

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "VW_CVC_REQUEST" (101 columns here) AS 
  select 
  cl,
  c2,
  .
  .
  .
  c101

from Table_name@dblink_to_cvc_new WHERE LOCATION_ID = 80;

This is my create query like by using same Query i created views already, but this time i'm getting this LOB Locatior Error.

Comment: It seems that one (or more) of 101 columns is a LOB. I told you what to do in my previous comment.